# Give 403 error for rails-api root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I'm creating  mobile api using rails-api and when a user goes to the url for the api, I get the expected "Welcome Aboard" page.  What I want to do is remove this and just give the user a 403 page (or 404), if the user attempts to go to the root url with a web browser.

I know that I can create a controller (error_pages), and then match it to a method (no_access) in routes.rb, and then have a page that is rendered by default in the views directory.

```
root 'error_pages#no_access' # in routes.rb
```

I'm assuming that there would be an easier way to accomplish this with Rails magic.

Edit:

I found this SO article:

[Where is the default "Welcome Aboard" page located in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964830/where-is-the-default-welcome-aboard-page-located-in-my-app)

It states that beginning with Rails 4, the index.html is no longer in the public/ directory, as it is contained in a gem.

Is it possible in the routes.rb file to just point to one of the error pages in the public directory?

I tried the following and it doesn't work:

root 'public/404.html'

I would hate to create a controller to just point to an error page, is there a better rails way?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `public/index.html`. That will result in a **404 (not found)** response for requests to the root path.

Comment: Since i'm using the rails-api gem, no index.html is created in the public directory.  Does this mean that I will just get the "Welcome" page in the dev environment, but once it's pushed to prod (in my case Heroku), it will be a 404?

Comment: I just tested it and the file is created in my case. Can you double check it's not there please?

Comment: It looks like starting with Rails 4, the index.html page isn't located in the public directory.  I've updated the question.